# Вращение точки в плоскости XYZ

Tags: c#, геометрия

Построил ось в пространстве XYZ. если смотреть перпендикулярно оси z(она у меня направлена в плоскость экрана), то ось построена по графику y = x;

[image: модель атома Резерфорда]

Если посмотреть под углом, что видно, что это орбита.

[image: модель под углом]

Строил орбиту(ось) по следующему алгоритму

```
public void Draw(TransformMatrix transform2)
{
  TPoint buf5 = new TPoint();
  for (int l = 0; l < 180; l ++)
  {
      buf5.setX(270 * Math.Cos(45) * Math.Cos(l) + 350);
      buf5.setZ(270 * Math.Sin(l));
      buf5.setY(-270 * Math.Cos(45) * Math.Cos(l) + 350);
 
      TPoint _p5 = buf5.ToView(transform2);
      zbuffer.setColor(_p5.getIntX(), _p5.getIntY(),
              Color.FromArgb((int)(_p5.getColor().R * 1), (int)         (_p5.getColor().G * 0), (int)(_p5.getColor().B * 1)));
   }
}
```

где **ToView(transform2)** отображение точки в 3D в 2D.

```
public TPoint ToView(TransformMatrix view)
{ 
  TPoint vp = new TPoint();
  vp.setX(x * view.matrix[0, 0] + y * view.matrix[1, 0] +
    z * view.matrix[2, 0] + view.matrix[3, 0]); 
  vp.setY(x * view.matrix[0, 1] + y * view.matrix[1, 1] +
    z * view.matrix[2, 1] + view.matrix[3, 1]);
  vp.setZ(x * view.matrix[0, 2] + y * view.matrix[1, 2] +
    z * view.matrix[2, 2] + view.matrix[3, 2]);
  return vp;
}
```

По данной орбите у меня вращается сфера(это электрон). Но проблема в том, что она вращается не по окружности(т.е. не по орбите) а по какому-то эллипсу. Я не пойму в чем дело.
Вращаю я его следующим образом.

```
public double [,] matrix = {
            {1, 0, 0, 0},
            {0, 1, 0, 0},
            {0, 0, 1, 0},
            {0, 0, 0, 1}
        };
public void RotateXY(double angle)
       {
           
           mult_matrix(RotationX(angle));
           mult_matrix(RotationY(angle));
       }
public double[,] RotationX(double angle)
        {
            double[,] buf = {
                {1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, Math.Cos(angle), Math.Sin(angle), 0},
                {0, -Math.Sin(angle), Math.Cos(angle), 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 1}
            };
            return buf;
        }
        public double[,] RotationY(double angle)
        {
            double[,] buf = {
                {Math.Cos(angle), 0, -Math.Sin(angle), 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 0},
                {Math.Sin(angle), 0, Math.Cos(angle), 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 1}
            };
            return buf;
        }
private void mult_matrix(double[,] transform)
{
  double [,] buf = new double [4,4];
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
        buf[i, j] = 0;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        buf[i, j] += matrix[i, k] * transform[k,j];
      }
  matrix = buf;
}
```

т.е. использую матрицы перехода. Но где-то в этом преобразовании у меня ошибка.
Спасибо.